# Insert date into a SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe4

As a part of a parametrized query I am trying to insert date from the plannerCalendar.

```
Params.ParamByName('D').AsDate := JulianDateToDateTime(PlannerCalendar1.Date);
```

This will not work.

Any ides ?

EDIT :

Even a simpla date insert will not work:

```
with ClientdataSet1 do
begin
Close;
CommandText :='';
CommandText :='INSERT INTO TLOG (DATE) VALUES (:D)';
Params.ParamByName('D').Value :=  Plannercalendar1.Date;
Execute;
```

I get :

[image]

When I do this (just to test) :

```
CommandText :='INSERT INTO TLOG (DATE) VALUES (date(julianday("now", "LOCALTIME")))';
```

The date gets inserted.

When I use this (looks promising) :

```
Params.ParamByName('D').Value := DateTimeToJulianDate(Plannercalendar1.Date);
```

The date inserted in the database is OK but the cxgrid displays  the date funny (bellow):

[image: Funny date display in the cxgrid]

Changing of the parameter does not help either.

> VALUES (julianday(:D),

If I change the DATE field to CHAR in the database then the :

```
DateToStr(Plannercalendar1.Date);
```

works properly....

Comment: From your previous questions, I'm assuming that you are using TMS Planner. Why are you using JulianDateToDateTime? What's wrong with just using PlannerCalendar1.Date?

Comment: Any ideas on what ? On why do you think it will not work ?

Comment: It does not work. It works on nearly all databases except SQLite. If I put Plannercalendar1.Date, the date is not right (1899).

Comment: It still makes not much sense to me. Delphi date time origins in 1899. Are you sure the value of the stored or read date time value is not 0 ?

Comment: Right now I am getting "Remote error: feature not implemented" when trying to use "Params.ParamByName('D').Value := Plannercalendar1.Date;"

Comment: Try posting your full problem code (including the SQL of your query) rather than a single line and expecting us to deduce everything from that.

Comment: Which library do you use to access to SQLite3? By itself, [SQlite3 has 3 potential date/time types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). The easiest is perhaps to use directly julian date as REAL or unix time as integer: `Params.ParamByName('D').AsInt64 := DateTimeToUnix(PlannerCalendar1.Date);`

Comment: For your information: When using https://github.com/stijnsanders/TSQLite I had the exact opposite: http://yoy.be/item.asp?i3065

Comment: @Stijn Sanders - how am I to rephrase my query then ?

Comment: No, I don't mean you should change your question. I was inserting TDateTime values in a SQLite table, and retrieval worked just nice, but manipulations in SQL takes other code since SQLite sees them as floating point values, the way Delphi stores TDateTime internally.

Answer (score 0):

I store datetime in SQL timestamps:

```
SomeQuery.ParamByName('PARAM').AsSQLTimeStamp := DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp(Now);
SomeDateTime := SQLTimeStampToDateTime(SomeQuery.ParamByName('PARAM').AsSQLTimeStamp);
```

Take a look at this functions From **Data.SqlTimSt** unit:

[DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SqlTimSt_DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp.html)

[SQLTimeStampToDateTime](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SqlTimSt_SQLTimeStampToDateTime.html)

Comment: I tried : "Params.ParamByName('D').AsSQLTimeStamp:= DateTimeToSQLTimeStamp(Now);" but I get "Remote error : feature not implemented"